# key pair value extraction in tree

Tags: python, tree, nltk

I am getting tree structure from nltk, and while accessing tree value I am getting result as follow:

```
(NE Stallone/NNP)
('jason', 'NN')
("'s", 'POS')
('film', 'NN')
(NE Rocky/NNP)
('was', 'VBD')
('inducted', 'VBN')
('into', 'IN')
('the', 'DT')
(NE National/NNP Film/NNP Registry/NNP)
('as', 'IN')
('well', 'RB')
('as', 'IN')
('having', 'VBG')
('its', 'PRP$')
('film', 'NN')
('props', 'NNS')
('placed', 'VBN')
('in', 'IN')
('the', 'DT')
(NE Smithsonian/NNP Museum/NNP)
('.', '.')
```

How can I retrieve values for `NN`, `VBN` only?

I tried this way :

```
text = "Stallone jason's film Rocky was inducted into the National Film Registry as well as having its film props placed in the Smithsonian Museum."

tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged, binary = True)
print namedEnt
np = [' '.join([y[0] for y in x.leaves()]) for x in namedEnt if x == "NN"]

for x in namedEnt:
    if x[0] == 'NN':
        print x[1]
```

`np = [' '.join([y[0] for y in x.leaves()]) for x in namedEnt if x == "NN"]` gave me NE tags correctly but could not get NN, NNP, NNS separately. Let me know if other way around to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you must just do a small swap in your key/value lookup. Also, you must consider the case the tuple has a single value with a try/except. Here is a small method that will allow you to retrieve the desired value from a tree :

```
def values_for(tree, tag):
    ret = []
    for x in tree:
        try:
            if x[1] == tag:
                ret.append(x[0])
        except IndexError, e:
            pass
    return ret
```

Then you should be able to filter the nodes you want :

```
>>> text = "Stallone jason's film Rocky was inducted into the National Film Registry as well as having its film props placed in the Smithsonian Museum."
>>> tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
>>> namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged, binary = True)
>>> values_for(namedEnt, 'NN')
['jason', 'film', 'film']
>>> values_for(namedEnt, 'VBN')
['inducted', 'placed']
>>> values_for(namedEnt, 'NNP')
[]
>>> values_for(namedEnt, 'NNS')
['props']
```

Hope this helps. Cheers !